# When Time Travel Machine in Doraemon Doesn't Solve Their Problem

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, anime, episode-identification, doraemon

I am trying to locate the scene in a Doraemon show where Nobita, Doraemon and the gang has to use time travel machine again and again, their face starts from being excited to normal to frustration at the end because they need to time travel again and again. Anybody can point me to where can I find this particular scene?

Comment: From what I can gather, there have been three _Doraemon_ anime shows in total, in 1973, 1979 and 2005 respectively. Would the episode you're referring to have been from the 2005 show?

Comment: @LogicDictates - Multiple shows and [multiple time machines](https://doraemon.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Machine)

Comment: for some reason this reminds me of the episode with Doraemon forcing multiple versions of himself to work on Nobita's homework overnight. Since because of the paradox every new future self would know when the past version would come, they quickly become more and more angry, until the last "Future Doraemon" attack the present one on sight.